# Как проверить на наличие изображения (CarrierWave)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть таблица lessons. В таблице есть поле cover. Туда и помещается имя файла после загрузки.

Есть N записей. Каждую запись вывожу циклом. В цикле для теста прописал это:

```
<%= lesson.cover %>
<br>
<%= lesson.cover.present? %>
```

У одной записи загрузил файл. В таблице имя файла у этой записи имеется. Файл на сервере имеется.

В результате после прохождения цикла, каждый урок имеет 1 пустую строку (тут речь о HTML) и одну строку с false, но один урок (у которого загружен cover) имеет это:

```
/uploads/lesson/cover/3/b4eef2e86d1c754f.jpg 
false
```

И я не понимаю что это и как это возможно... В другом моем проекте есть точно такая же строка - `resource.cover.present?`, но только она там работает.

**Добавлено:**

Решил проблему добавлением `.url`:

```
lesson.cover.url.present?
```

Но, как я уже писал выше, в другом моем проекте без каких-либо проблем работает этот вариант:

```
resource.cover.present?
```

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Если вызывать lesson.cover то возвращается объект вашего CarrierWave Uploader.
Правильнее проверять так(возвращена будет именно ссылка, а если ее нет, то nil):

```
lesson.cover_url # вернет nil если картинка отсутствует
```

так что правильнее проверять так:

```
lesson.cover_url.present?
```